# Error in changing the value state of input box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

My input box is not editable when I try to edit the value in it.

I am not sure if my onChange event is being used properly to change the value of the input.

```
import React from "react";

import * as TodoActions from "../actions/TodoActions";
import TodoStore from "../stores/TodoStore";

export default class Todo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
  }

  deleteTodo() {
    TodoActions.deleteTodo(this.props.id);
  }

  toggleEdit() {
    TodoActions.toggleEdit(this.props.id);
  }

  updateTodo() {
    TodoActions.updateTodo(this.props.text);
  }

  toggleComplete() {
    TodoActions.toggleComplete(this.props.id);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    console.log('e.taget.value: '+ e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(value);

  }

  render() {
    const buttonStyle = { margin: "5px" };

    const { complete, edit, text, id } = this.props;

    const icon = complete ? "\u2714" : "\u2716"

    if (edit) {
      return (
        <li>
          <form onSubmit={this.updateTodo.bind(this)}>
            <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={text} focus="focused"/>
            <button onClick={this.toggleEdit.bind(this)} class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style={buttonStyle}>Cancel</button>
            <button onClick={this.updateTodo.bind(this)} class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style={buttonStyle}>Update</button>
          </form>
        </li>
      );
    }

    return (
      <li>
        <span>{text}</span>
        <span onClick={this.toggleComplete.bind(this)} class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style={buttonStyle}>{icon}</span>
        <button onClick={this.toggleEdit.bind(this)} class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style={buttonStyle}>Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.deleteTodo.bind(this)} class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style={buttonStyle}>Delete</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `e.target.value`, not `value`? Also, your `super` call should be  `super(props)`

Comment: @AndrewLi `console.log('e.taget.value: '+ e.target.value);` is working and displaying in my console. The code is for a todo app and when I click the `Edit` button this new form comes up where the value is placed into an input box for me to edit. However, it is not letting me edit the text and I am trying to figure out how to place it into a new variable that I can pass on

Comment: But what is `value`? It's not defined thus the error...

Comment: You're right I had to define it, I guess I was just not doing it right. I put `const { value } = this.props;` in my onChange function and got it working with other help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<input/>` should be a controlled component as your are using `value` prop.

Try this

```
 <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.value || text} focus="focused"/>
```

And add an empty state to your `constructor`

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {}
}
```

Comment: I made these changes and created `const { value } = this.props;` in my onChange function and it is working. Could you explain what your changes are doing?

Comment: You need to set the value from the state because your input box is a controlled component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: @ByteSettlement Are you sure you want to mix editing state and props in your code? This answer actually fixes it by keeping it in the `state`, while mine tries to keep it in `props`.

Comment: @slomek I'm not editing the `state` either. `this.state.value || text` this means, take state if available else use the props. Once onchange is called, state will be available.

Comment: Yep, you're right about not editing `props`, I was wrong with that. But you do edit state (by using `setState` but render value `text` from `props`). Maybe you should pass `text.props` to `state.props` first, and then edit it there?

Comment: @slomek The initial render will take `value` from props. Once the onchange is triggered `this.state.value` will supply the value. Not the props.

Comment: Now when I want to update that input I wont be able to call `TodoActions.updateTodo(this.props.text);` I'll have to do `TodoActions.updateTodo(this.state.value);` correct?

Comment: @ByteSettlement Exactly!

Comment: @PraneshRavi My todo app is using Flux however, so how will I create a action that sends this.state.value to be able to update the object in the store with the new value?

Comment: @ByteSettlement You've a proper setup. Create an action to store the value in the store and call that action inside onChange function.

Answer (score 0):

If your `text` property is not set, then it is passed as `null` to the input, which is equivalent to not passing it at all. In this situation, the input is rendered as *uncontrolled* and you cannot change its value via props.

In this case, the best approach is to set default values for your property, to make sure that it's an empty string at least:

```
Todo.defaultProps = {
    text: ''
};
```

Add this to the end and you should be safe that the input is always *controlled*.